# How to modify classpath in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, classpath

Again, I saw this sentence:

> A .classpath file snippet that can be included in your project's
>   .classpath has been provided here(ie, a link). Please only use the
>   classpathentry's you actually need (see below for details).

What do these sentences mean and how can I add that code snippet to my classpath file in eclipse ?

Please help.

Comment: Whomever wrote that "advice" should be questioned about it. Certainly the audience for such "advice" should NOT be anyone who doesn't know what the `.classpath` file is or how to find it. Maybe if you shared the full context of that sentence, we could provide better interpretation of what it mean.

Comment: Its in the readme.html file for Google APIs Client Library for Java 1.10.3-beta. The API and the readme file may be downloaded at:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Generated_libraries_for_Google_APIs

The name of the link/file is:
google-api-java-client-1.10.3-beta.zip

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although you can modify the .classpath file, Eclipse manages this file for you automatically every time you change the Java Build Path properties of your project.  This is a better approach than manually changing the file.

Answer (score 13):

I understand this as you want to find the classpath *file*. Go to eclipse and press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`R`. Type `.classpath` and select the file in your project.

Note: If you're modifying this file and you don't know what it is, I advise you be extra careful :).